# Why cant array_flip work in my php script?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to reverse the keys and values of this string but it seems not to be working. What might be the issue?

```
$input = '"85"=>"1","86"=>"2","87"=>"3","88"=>"4","89"=>"5","90"=>"6","91"=>"7","92"=>"8","93"=>"9","94"=>"10","95"=>"11","96"=>"12","97"=>"13","98"=>"14","99"=>"15","100"=>"16","101"=>"17","102"=>"18","103"=>"19","104"=>"20","105"=>"21","106"=>"22","107"=>"23","108"=>"24","109"=>"25","110"=>"26","111"=>"27","112"=>"28","113"=>"29","114"=>"30","115"=>"31","116"=>"32","117"=>"33","118"=>"34","119"=>"35","120"=>"36","121"=>"37","122"=>"38","123"=>"39","124"=>"40","125"=>"41","126"=>"42","127"=>"43","128"=>"44","129"=>"45","130"=>"46","131"=>"47","132"=>"48","133"=>"49","134"=>"50","135"=>"51","136"=>"52","137"=>"53","138"=>"54","139"=>"55","140"=>"56","141"=>"57","142"=>"58","143"=>"59","144"=>"60","145"=>"61","146"=>"62","147"=>"63","148"=>"64","149"=>"65","150"=>"66","151"=>"67","152"=>"68","153"=>"69","154"=>"70","155"=>"71","156"=>"72","157"=>"73","158"=>"74","159"=>"75","160"=>"76","161"=>"77","162"=>"78","163"=>"79","164"=>"80","165"=>"81","166"=>"82","167"=>"83","168"=>"84","169"=>"85","170"=>"86","171"=>"87","172"=>"88","173"=>"89","174"=>"90","175"=>"91","176"=>"92","177"=>"93","178"=>"94","179"=>"95","180"=>"96","181"=>"97","182"=>"98","183"=>"99","184"=>"100","185"=>"101","186"=>"102","187"=>"103","188"=>"104","189"=>"105","190"=>"106","191"=>"107","192"=>"108","193"=>"109","194"=>"110","195"=>"111","196"=>"112","197"=>"113","198"=>"114","199"=>"115","200"=>"116","201"=>"117","202"=>"118","203"=>"119","204"=>"120","205"=>"121","206"=>"122","207"=>"123","208"=>"124","209"=>"125","210"=>"126"';
$result = array($input);
$result=array_flip($result);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: As the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) say, the parameter **must** be an array, you can't pass a string as a parameter for this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array($input)` does not return what you think it does. `array` does not parse your string. So you'll have to do that first. If your input string does not use `=>` anywhere else than where it divides a key and value, then you could do a replacement to make it JSON, and then decode it:

```
$result = json_decode("{" . str_replace("=>", ":", $input) . "}", true);
$result = array_flip($result);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not be realizing but your `$result` array has just **one element**, which is a giant string in the form of `'"85"=>"1","86"=>"2", ...`. You have to create the `$result` array like this,

```
$result = array("85"=>"1","86"=>"2","87"=>"3", ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first process your input into an array first as    `array_flip()` doesn't work on strings, you can split your input into a couple of sub parts by using a `,` delimiter first and then process it the second time with a `=>` delimiter, which is enough to tell your you're doing the right thing the wrong way